# Unable to launch an App using appium on android emulator

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium

Unable to launch app, please find the below trace for the same

Note: same app works with calabash i.e i am able to launch the app

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error occured
>   while starting App. Original error: Activity used to start app doesn't
>   exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable
>   activity (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)
>           Command duration or timeout: 11.16 seconds
>           Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: 'zasdqweqwe123', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
>           System info: host: 'WNnsMM012sampel', ip: '10.2.3.1sampel', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_131'
>           Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
>             at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>             at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>             at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>             at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>             at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:51)
>             at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>             at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>             at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
>             at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>             at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
>             at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:47)
>             at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:114)
>             at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:132)
>             at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:97)
>             at tests.BaseAppiumTest.setAppium(BaseAppiumTest.java:34)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>             at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>             at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>             at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>             at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>             at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>             at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>             at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>             at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>             at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>             at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>             at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>             at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>             at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>             at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>             at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>             at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>             at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>             at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>             at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>             at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>
> ```
>     java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at tests.BaseAppiumTest.teardown(BaseAppiumTest.java:40)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
> ```

I am using below capabilities:

```
public class BaseAppiumTest 
{
    AndroidDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setAppium() throws MalformedURLException {
        File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/apps/");
        File app = new File(appDir, "automation_test_artifact.apk");
        AppiumUtils appium = new AppiumUtils();
        appium.devicename = "Android Emulator";
        appium.app=app.getAbsolutePath();
        appium.appPackage="com.morrisons.instore.sit";
        appium.appActivity=".HomeActivity";
        appium.platformVersion="4.4";

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = appium.getCapabilities();
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }

    @After
    public void teardown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: which version of Appium are you using? make sure that u use the last one

Comment: Have you tried pre-pending the package before the activity?  `appium.appActivity="com.morrisons.instore.sit.HomeActivity"`

Answer (score 1):

Try finding out the launchable activity name of the app that you are trying to run.Sometimes it's possible that the launchable-activity name is not given in the androidmanifest.xml file.You can use the following commands to verify if the launchable-activity name is present or not :

```
aapt dump badging <path-to-apk> | grep launchable-activity:\ name
```